# .module file not being discovered

Tags: 8

I am developing a custom Drupal 8 module on my local VM. When I first created and enabled my module, it did not have a `.module` file (just a controller). Now I have added a `.module` file so I can add an implementation of `hook_entity_insert()` but Drupal is not discovering it. I have tried going to Configuration > Performance > 'Clear all caches' but no joy!

How can I get Drupal 8 to discover the `.module` file in my custom module?

Comment: Did you add your .info.yml file along side the .module file? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file

Answer (score 6):

Just clearing cache is not enough, you need to *uninstall* and then *re-install* your module in order for the `.module` file to be discovered.

In the **Admin panel** go to **Extend** and select the **Uninstall tab**. Select your custom module and click the **Uninstall button**. Now go back to the **List tab** and re-enable your module as before. Your implementation of `hook_entity_insert()` should now be recognised.

Comment: With the Devel module enabled you can simply use `drush dre MYMODULE`.

Comment: the ```drush dre MYMODULE``` works like a charm.   Thanks!